# Omitting jobs off of application

Tags: applications

I’m looking at a job application, and in the work experience section, it just says “work experience.”

Since it wasn’t very specific about listing “all jobs in the past five years,” or something like that, would it be OK to leave off jobs that I don’t want on there as long as there is no employment gap?

Comment: I think it depends on where the gap is. For example, if between now and the last relevant job was years ago, that might come into play. But suppose you recently have relevant experience but between the current and last relevant experience was 5 years ago due to a lay off and inability to find a related job. That might make sense for a gap.

Answer (score 1):

Especially for an online application, the purpose behind asking for employment history is to be able to put together a picture of your experience *relating to the position*. If you feel like some jobs you worked are not quite relevant or will not help the recruiters during the process for any reason, there is nothing wrong with leaving them off.